# Can't add a Phaser JS state

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to add and start a state in Phaser JS but I'm getting a weird error. Here is the code:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO);

var GameState = {
preload: function(){
},

create: function(){
},

update: function(){
}

};

game.state.add('GameState', GameState);
game.state.start(GameState);
```

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
>       at main.js:18

Comment: I tossed your code into [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5o1qhgoo/1/) and the only error I got was `Phaser.StateManager - No state found with the key: [object Object]`. If you [change the `start` call to use a string](https://jsfiddle.net/5o1qhgoo/2/) then it works without issue. What version of Phaser are you using and is there any other code that you haven't shared?

Comment: I used the file from their web site (version 3.2.1) now that i included your version (<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.6.2/phaser.js"></script>) it works, sorry i wasnt paying attenction to the version and didnt expect the states to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are big changes between Phaser 2 and Phaser 3. As of this moment Phaser 2 is very well documented and most example code you find will be using it. Phaser 3 docs are still being baked.

Answer (score 1):

That typically means you are trying to access a variable that hasn't been defined.

Look for a place in the code where you use `.add(` on some object. What ever that object is, at the time the code runs, it is not defined, meaning it has not been initialized with any value.

It looks like you're following the example in the documentation correctly - 
https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Game.html

> In its most simplest form, a Phaser game can be created by providing the arguments to the constructor:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create });
```

> In the example above it is passing in a State object directly. You can
>   also use the State Manager to do this:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO);
game.state.add('Boot', BasicGame.Boot);
game.state.add('Preloader', BasicGame.Preloader);
game.state.add('MainMenu', BasicGame.MainMenu);
game.state.add('Game', BasicGame.Game);
game.state.start('Boot');
```

> In the example above, 4 States are added to the State Manager, and
>   Phaser is told to start running the Boot state when it has finished
>   initializing. There are example project templates you can use in the
>   Phaser GitHub repo, inside the resources folder.
>
> Instead of specifying arguments you can also pass a single object
>   instead:

```
var config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    renderer: Phaser.AUTO,
    antialias: true,
    multiTexture: true,
    state: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

But the documentation is contradictory because it says that `state` by default is `null`.

> Parameters:
>
> state object   null  The default state object. A object
>   consisting of Phaser.State functions (preload, create, update, render)
>   or null.

The state manager hasn't been initialized into `game.state`. Try using the verison where you pass the states in with the `new Phaser.Game()` call.

Comment: Does Not work, i've worked with states in phaser before and everything went perfectly.

Comment: The `StateManager` being initialized or not shouldn't have any bearing on wether a default state was passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

looking in your code you forgot to add the ''.

game.state.start(GameState) -> error
game.state.start("GameState") -> success